# How can I disable showing the value of a Spring @Value annotation in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am running IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 (Ultimate Edition).  I have a Spring Boot project, with Spring properties defined that will get autowired into `@Value`-annotated fields in an `@Component` class.  The properties are defined in application.properties.

By default, IntelliJ is displaying the value of the variable instead of the actual variable expression (with a color scheme to make it obvious that this is not the actual value in there).  Clicking on the value will reveal the actual variable expression.

For instance:

```
@Value("${my.property.value}")
private String myProperty;
```

would be displayed as the following, if "my.property.value" resolved to "theValue":

```
@Value("theValue")
private String myProperty;
```

I would rather it not do this.  Is there a preference to disable this?  I have not had luck finding an answer searching the IDEA preferences or online.

Comment: Weird, I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2017.3.4 (Ultimate Edition) with Spring Boot 2 and it isn't doing that by default.

Comment: what is your property file? `.yaml` or `.propeties`

Comment: @Generic — application.properties

Comment: if you use `.yaml` it will work.

Comment: I suppose that option must be in Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Spring

Comment: @Generic I use `.properties` and it works like he wants by default.

Comment: I have trouble replicating the issue using the Community Edition. But try wrapping the property reference in Spring expression language tag: #{${my.property.value}}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Settings(Preferences on Mac) | Editor | General | Code Folding disable the option **I18 strings**.

This [folding](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/code-foldings-for-i18n-support) feature is not related to Spring specifically.

Comment: I confirmed that this works.  This was super misleading, since (in my case, at least), these are definitely not internationalized strings.

Comment: Jetbrains could definitely make this clearer by calling it "property resolution" or something.   Trying to find this setting drove me nuts for days.

Comment: Feel free to leave your feedback here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191687

Comment: It works. FYI you may need to reopen the file. ; )

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer did not help me. However you can specifically deactivate the validation of the Spring Boot .properties or .yaml Files by going to the right corner of your IDE (in default mode) and click:

```
Inspector | Configure inspections
```

In the Popup search for

```
Spring | Spring Boot | Spring Boot application.yml
Spring | Spring Boot | Spring Boot application.properties
```